# Golang: `dial tcp 172.20.0.7:8081: connect: connection refused`, error at random times between docker containers / services

Tags: docker, go, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've a `docker-compose` file with contents like this

```
# Docker Compose file Reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

version: '3'

services:

  john:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/cowboys/John/Dockerfile
      args:
        - COWBOY_NAME_JOHN
        - CONTAINER_PORT_JOHN
    ports:
      - "8081:8081" # Forward the exposed port on the container to port on the host machine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - fullstack
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db


  philip:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/cowboys/Philip/Dockerfile
      args:
        - COWBOY_NAME_PHILIP
        - CONTAINER_PORT_PHILIP
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - fullstack
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db

  db:
    build:
      context: Dockerfiles/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - fullstack
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD

networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` ( or `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` to reinitialise db on next run), I get an error like this

`sam_1     | panic: Put "http://john:8081/shoot": dial tcp 172.20.0.7:8081: connect: connection refused`

`john` is one of the services name under `services`. Here is complete screenshot:

[image]

Link to repository where all details could be seen including environment variables & relevant Dockerfile(s) - `https://github.com/sitetester/distributed-cowboys`

Could anyone please explain how to get rid of this error ? It just happens/occurs at random time. Not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's impossible know without code.  Can you make a minimal reproducible example? From what you're showing so far,  my guess is that the john service is having issues,  the last output is ``` has joined the battle`  which seems a little suspect.   Are you logging all errors?  Take out the restart clauses and see if your app is crashing and restarting,  though is expect docker compose logs in that case.   But you should not need to restart the service anyway because they shouldn't be crashing,  and if they are that's something you need to fix

Comment: @DanielFarrell, thank you for response. Link to repo is already mentioned above i.e. https://github.com/sitetester/distributed-cowboys

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:** removing existing containers/images and pruning docker volumes fixed the issue.